# Application Insights: When sampling is enabled, are calls to TrackTrace affected?

Tags: logging, azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service

I'm using Application Insights for my Azure web app. I like the idea of sampling certain kinds of metrics to keep the volume manageable, but I want to ensure that every message my server-side code traces using TrackTrace is stored.

If I have sampling enabled, will trace messages created via calls to TrackTrace also be sampled? If so, is there a way to selectively say not to sample such messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify ApplicationInsights.config to tune sampling settings or you can access the same classes in code:

Under `<AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor>` node, you can add:

```
<ExcludedTypes>Trace</ExcludedTypes>
```

This will exclude Traces from sampling. If there are several nodes of `<AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor>` already, modify the first one that includes Traces (either explicitly or implicitly by not excluding them).

Relevant documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-sampling#adaptive-sampling-at-your-web-server).